# Interfacing push button switches with Raspberry pi 2

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi, gpio, interfacing

I am making a `Braille keyboard`, and I need help in interfacing buttons with RPi. As Braille is a 3*2 matrix, I will be connecting push button switches according to the braille matrix.

Problem statement: If I press button `1*1`, on my text editor, `'A'` must get typed.

Similarly, if I press button `1*1 & 1*2` simultaneously, `'B'` must get typed.

Comment: What is your question? You explained what you want to do, but haven't shown any code. Is there a particular problem in your implementation you are having difficulty with?

Comment: So you want encode inputs ?